# Import/Export Core Data to XML file

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm currently trying to create my Core Data object graph with an xml file. I have come across a lot of information and it seems there isn't any easy way to do it.

So I just want to make sure if this really is correct so I dont use a lot of time writing the code myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For importing data there is no predefined automatically working way.

You will have to import the data by writing code. The amount of code necessary depends on your data.

[ADC Article on efficiently importing data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html)